# Copy a row if there is only one record for that group

Tags: r, dplyr, data-cleaning

I have some pre-post data (in R) for which some individuals only have a value for time 1, like episode "2" here:

```
episode <- c('1','1','2','3','3')
score <- c('44','12','37','40','9')

df <- data.frame(episode,score)
```

For all the records where there is only "pre" data (1 score per episode), I would like to use R (dplyr preferred) to copy that record and then indicate for all records which is the pre and which is the post. So the final should look something like:

| episode | score | time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 44 | 1 |
| 1 | 12 | 2 |
| 2 | 37 | 1 |
| 2 | 37 | 2 |
| 3 | 40 | 1 |
| 3 | 9 | 2 |

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option - create a column of frequency count by 'episode' and if the value is 1, then add 1 on the logical (`n == 1`) and replicate the rows with `uncount`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
 add_count(episode) %>% 
 mutate(n = (n == 1) + 1) %>%
 uncount(n) %>%
 group_by(episode) %>%
 mutate(time = row_number()) %>%
 ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 × 3
  episode score  time
  <chr>   <chr> <int>
1 1       44        1
2 1       12        2
3 2       37        1
4 2       37        2
5 3       40        1
6 3       9         2
```

---

Or create the 'time' column first and then use `complete` with `fill`

```
df %>% 
  group_by(episode) %>%
  mutate(time = row_number()) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  complete(episode, time) %>%
  fill(score)
```

Comment: The second one worked perfectly, thanks!